# Scrolling of Top view is little bit faster than bottom view in Android app

Tags: android, uiscrollview, google-play, android-scrollview

I have notice one thing about play store app that scrolling of upper view is fast as compare to the bottom view. I am thinking about it how it will be managed but didn't get any clue. Please let me know if anyone can guide me on this. Please see the screen shot for more understanding.

[image: Sample Picture that shows two view - upper and lower]

Here the Cut the Rope2 view i.e upper view scrolled faster than the lower view. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by listening for the user scroll, and updating the margin of the background ImageView.

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        int scrollY = rootScrollView.getScrollY(); 
        imageView.getLayoutParams().topMargin = -scrollY * 2; // Higher this multiplier is, the faster the parallax effect
    }
});
```